# angularjs grid shows wrong date

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code shows data on a grid. In the grid, date column value alone is wrong and its 2 days behind from the value in DB. For example if its 2017/10/1 in DB, it shows 2017/29/9 on grid. On my server side the date value is correct. Also during post, right value is inserted into DB. I tried to use filter and moment like shown below, but no luck. I am using dalelotts datetimepicker.

**In Controller:**

```
$scope.availablePartTemp = Part.get_resource.query(function(response) {
            angular.forEach(response, function(item) {
                if (item) { 
                //tried using filter/moment here to convert date format
                var y = moment(item.date).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS") + 'Z';
                    console.log('y=' + y);
                    var x = $filter('date')(item.date, "dd/MM/yyyy"); 
                    console.log('x=' + x);
                 $scope.availablePart.push(item);
                }
            });
        });
```

**In HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="date" class="form-control" data-ng-model="part.date" name="date" >                        
<datetimepicker data-ng-model="part.date"  
                data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown1', startView:'day', 
                                               minView:'day', modelType: 'YYYY-MM-DD' }"  
                data-on-set-time="correctDateFormat()" >
</datetimepicker>
```

Comment: Any suggestions Please.

Comment: A live example would be helpful. It is difficult to determine the problem given the example you have here.

try this:

`$scope.availablePart = response.map(function(item) {return  moment(item.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

The date-time picker is configured to accept the dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format.

Remember, the format of the data in the model and what is displayed to the user do no need to match - this is the purpose of filters and formatters.